# Custom module in Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am new to *NodeJS* programming so I was trying make simple custom module by **extending** one module to another which prints in console log.

**ExtendMod.js**

```js
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.tutorial = function() {
  console.log("N Tutotial");
}
```

**app.js**

```js
var Tutor=require('./ExtendMod.js');

exports.NodeTutorial = function() {
  console.log("Node Tutorial")

  function pTutor() {
    var PTutor=Tutor
    PTutor.tutorial;
  }
}

console.log(require('./thirdNode.js').NodeTutorial());
```

I have extended `ExtendMod.js` in `app.js`.

**Question:** Why an empty braces after exports when we create my first module and also in `app.js` we didn't take exports as a variable is it global?

**My output :**

- Node Tutorial
- N Tutorial
- Undefined

What is this undefined?

Comment: Remove `var exports = module.exports = {}`. You're overriding a global variable

Comment: @AlbertoSchiabel still not working nothing on console log and I guess wee need to initialize global variable once

Comment: PTutor.tutorial; is not a function call you should PTutor.tutorial(); and in your app.js there is no any call also.

Comment: @serifcetiner not working